# Background de app

Tags: imagem, app, background

Eu gostaria de saber se há jeito de fazer triângulos com div's que são responsivos como o background de um aplicativo, ou se é melhor usar uma imagem vetorial.
Se me indicarem algum site com imagens veotoriais, eu ficaria bem feliz também.
Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer dessa forma:

```css
#triangulo{
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-width: 100px;
  border-color: green green transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangulo"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Ok! Obrigado. Porém eu preciso que ela seja responsiva e eu não acho jeito de fazer isso.

Comment: Ai eu já não sei. Acho que dá pra fazer com CSS3 canvas.

Comment: Se você tiver o uso de SVG em mente, acredito que seria possível usando o Inkscape.